# Codeigniter on Nginx generates https action for form, but not Apache

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, https, nginx

I have a Codeigniter app with a login form. I ran it both on Apache and Nginx. On Apache, everything works fine, and the form action is normal. But on Nginx, the form action uses `https` instead of `http`(which I don't want at the moment).

I generate the form using this:

```
<?php echo form_open(site_url('/user/do_login')); ?>
```

and it produces this:

```
<form action="https://example.com/index.php/user/do_login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

How can I force it to generate `http` instead of `https` on Nginx?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using the automatic site_url detection, Codeigniter's own http/https detection relies on the [`$_SERVER['HTTPS']` value to be `off`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/v2.1.0/system/core/Config.php#L71) if it is in fact set to something, to generate the `http` for the base_url.

Check your default fastcgi_params (usually `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`), maybe it sets it to an empty string or something other than "off", also you can force this from nginx config with this to be "off":

```
fastcgi_param  HTTPS off;
```

If you are using one `server` block for both the http and https connection inside the nginx's config file, you can use a [mapping](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) to create the value you need based on the `$scheme` variable:

```
# somewhere inside http { ... }
map $scheme $php_https { default off; https on; }
```

And reference it in the `fastcgi_param`:

```
fastcgi_param  HTTPS $php_https;
```

Comment: I forced it from the nginx config to `off` and it is solved now! Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Check your config.php on the Nginx box vs the Apache box.  site_url returns what you have specified in your $config['base_url'] entry in config.php

Comment: You are also right, but if empty CodeIgniter tries to automatically detect base_url